# stb_truetype calculating the dimensions of a string

Tags: opengl, truetype

I'm using [`stb_truetype`](https://github.com/nothings/stb/blob/master/stb_truetype.h) to render TrueType fonts in an OpenGL context.

Is there any simple way to pre-determine the height and width of a string in the font before it is rendered?

Comment: What does this have to do with OpenGL? Height/width calculations are a function of whatever font library you're using.

Comment: Only because I couldn't get a tag for stb

Comment: @Briggy Did you ever find a solution fr this? If so, please post it. If not, what language are you using? I found a way to do this in LWJGL 3's bindings to stb (so, Java) but I want to make sure that my answer is relevant before posting.

Comment: @Tophandour I was also using Java but this should be relevant to all languages which have stb bindings. I ended up summing the stbtt_GetCodepointHMetrics value for each character on a line, then scaling by stbtt_ScaleForPixelHeight.

Comment: @Briggy I was able to do this via different (though hopefully valid) means. I'll post my solution when I get home.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LWJGL STB True Type demo contains an implementation for this now (since August 2017), including kerning:

[lwjgl3 / Truetype.java](https://github.com/LWJGL/lwjgl3/blob/7ef51d1054aa4647bc8aafcfd3d93c6a6ad1410f/modules/samples/src/test/java/org/lwjgl/demo/stb/Truetype.java#L219):

```java
private float getStringWidth(STBTTFontinfo info, String text, int from, int to, int fontHeight) {
    int width = 0;

    try (MemoryStack stack = stackPush()) {
        IntBuffer pCodePoint       = stack.mallocInt(1);
        IntBuffer pAdvancedWidth   = stack.mallocInt(1);
        IntBuffer pLeftSideBearing = stack.mallocInt(1);

        int i = from;
        while (i < to) {
            i += getCP(text, to, i, pCodePoint);
            int cp = pCodePoint.get(0);

            stbtt_GetCodepointHMetrics(info, cp, pAdvancedWidth, pLeftSideBearing);
            width += pAdvancedWidth.get(0);

            if (isKerningEnabled() && i < to) {
                getCP(text, to, i, pCodePoint);
                width += stbtt_GetCodepointKernAdvance(info, cp, pCodePoint.get(0));
            }
        }
    }

    return width * stbtt_ScaleForPixelHeight(info, fontHeight);
}

private static int getCP(String text, int to, int i, IntBuffer cpOut) {
    char c1 = text.charAt(i);
    if (Character.isHighSurrogate(c1) && i + 1 < to) {
        char c2 = text.charAt(i + 1);
        if (Character.isLowSurrogate(c2)) {
            cpOut.put(0, Character.toCodePoint(c1, c2));
            return 2;
        }
    }
    cpOut.put(0, c1);
    return 1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get an approximate answer with the LWJGL 3.1.1 bindings to stb.

First, after calling `STBTruetype.stbtt_BakeFontBitmap(ByteBuffer data, float pixel_height, ByteBuffer pixels, int pw, int ph, int first_char, Buffer chardata)` when you load the font to begin with, hold onto the `chardata` buffer, which should be a `STBTTBakedChar.Buffer`, and also hold onto `first_char` which is an `int`.

Next, if you are trying to get the width of the 'M' character, for example, call `chardata.get('M' - first_char).x1() - chardata.get('M' - first_char).x0()` and the result should be the width of the character. You can do this for each character of a string and add up all of the values for the total width of the string.

I noticed that getting the width of the space character gives a result of 0 so this should just be used as an approximation. Personally, I multiplied the width of the 'M' character by the total length of the string in order to get an upper bound on the string's width.

Comment: This method is the method Initially used, but does not give you the correct value. It is a good approximation though

Comment: @Briggy right now in my code I'm approximating the length by getting the width of the 'M' character for the font and multiplying it by the string length because I needed to quickly get something working. I noticed that getting the width for the space character gives the result of 0, which is a problem if you iterate. I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 1):

While @Tophandour's answer gave a good approximation for the width, stb provides functions to do this more accurately. This is the solution I now use in Java:

```
public float getWidth(String text) {
    float length = 0f;
    for (int i = 0; i < text.length(); i++) {
        IntBuffer advancewidth = BufferUtils.createIntBuffer(1);
        IntBuffer leftsidebearing = BufferUtils.createIntBuffer(1);
        stbtt_GetCodepointHMetrics(info, (int)text.charAt(i), advancewidth, leftsidebearing);
        length += advancewidth.get(0);
    }
    return length * cscale;
}
```

where info is the font info object created via stbtt_InitFont and cscale is from stbtt_ScaleForPixelHeight.